# How to filter for ManyToMany that contains object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have objects like these:

```
class Pencil(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

class Box(models.Model):
   pencils = models.ManyToManyField(Pencil)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

let's say that I have a pencil with blue color:

```
pencil = Pencil.objects.create(color='blue')
```

and then I create some instances of Box class. And then I'm doing some filtering by name

```
boxes = Box.objects.filter(name__startswith='Big')
```

How can I filter further to get only boxes that have name starting from "Big" and that have a  pencil with blue color ? I cannot do something like `pencil.box_set.all()` because I've already did some filtering on boxes.

Comment: Can't you do the filtering on boxes later, e.g `pencil.box_set.filter(name__startswith='Big')`?  Seems simplest.

Comment: It's just an example. Actually I have a lot more complicated filtering and no, unfortunately I can't do it like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat many-to-many relationships exactly like one-to-many relations in filtering:

```
boxes = Box.objects.filter(name__startswith='Big', pencils__title='blue')
```

Comment: did you test it? i am not sure if it works since ``pencils`` is a ManyRelatedManager

Comment: @doniyor Yes, I've used it before.

Answer (score 1):

what about this one?

```
boxes = Box.objects.filter(name__startswith='Big', pencils__in=[Pencil.objects.filter(color='blue')])
```